# How mount (cifs) in Ubuntu a MacOS directory with all permissions

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, macosx, cifs

About mount purposes

If the client and server are both Linux (Ubuntu), and assuming that the user in the server is `omicron` with `uid 1007 gid 1007` the following command is viable to be executed in the client:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.X/samba_alias
                   /mnt/192.168.1.X/directoryname       
                   -o username=omicron,
                   rw,
                   uid=1007,
                   gid=1007
```

`uid` and `gid` are mandatory to be the same than omicron in the server otherwise is not possible create anything in the mounted directory. So, because any new files created from the client have the same uid and gid than the server's user, then the server can use them without any problem.

If the server is MacOS and client Ubuntu.

If through the GUI is used `smb://hostname/directorynameshared`, it is mounted, and is possible create anything and execute any script, it in:

*`$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/smb-share:server=hostname,share=directorynameshared`

The unique disadvantange is that in the server is not possible edit/access that new content because the user/groups are not the same, it is solved with `chown` in the server side. Anyway the directory is unmounted later.

Now, the reason of this post, if the following is used (Ubuntu to MacOS) - user in the server is `omicron` with `uid 505 gid 507`:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.X/directorynameshared
                   /mnt/192.168.1.X/directoryname       
                   -o username=omicron,
                   rw,
                   uid=505,
                   gid=507
```

Is possible execute the scripts, but is not possible create new content:

- `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘xyz’: Permission denied`

How solve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

On the MacOS Samba server, you'll need to ensure the connecting account has "Full Read/Write" permissions to the shared directory. From there, this connection string will work for a manual mount situation:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=omicron,username=omicron,password=superSecretPassword!123 //192.168.1.X/directorynameshared /mnt/192.168.1.X/directoryname
```

Note that the `uid` and `username` values are both the literal name of the account on the MacOS machine, and the `password` value is also explicitly provided. I've not encountered a situation with a MacOS Samba host where the `rw` or `gid` flags are required when manually mounting a share.

If you plan on adding the mount to your `/etc/fstab` file, there are a few extra things you'll need:

```
//192.168.1.X/directorynameshared       /mnt/192.168.1.X/directoryname  cifs uid=505,gid=507,username=omicron,password=superSecretPassword!123,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix 0 0
```

Note that when the share is mounted via `/etc/fstab`, the `uid` and `gid` values are required, as well as flags for `file_mode` and `dir_mode`, plus `nounix`. The `nounix` flag is particularly important if your Ubuntu Server is going to be writing files via Apache and other service utilities.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, on MacOS the new user created how `Standard` type is already applied/assigned to the directory to be shared with all the `"Full Read/Write"` permissions.  And yes, the `uid`, `gid` and `username` are based on the server's user. - BTW Why I should use the `/etc/fstab` approach?

Comment: I never said you *should* mount via `/etc/fstab`; I offered it as an option. Generally servers are static devices that operate in the same location with the same resources for great lengths of time. As a result, people generally automate as much of the server configuration as possible so that time is not spent on the machine after any reboot or system update. If you do not wish to auto-mount, that is your choice 

Comment: Thanks, I've already done a research about that, it is for automatic mount.